# Windows Address Bar Shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any shortcut to put focus on **taskbar** address bar on Windows 7?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not aware of a direct shortcut, but I use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Ok... I lied. I binded the above to an [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) shortcut. But that still counts as using it, right? :)

Comment: @RHaguiuda you are most welcome :)

Comment: Example using CTRL+SHIFT+L (similar to CTRL+L used in browser to access the address bar:)
`^+l:: Send, #b,+{Tab}`

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for this !

Alt+D

Works in browsers too !

Comment: The user is referring to the Address Bar toolbar that can be enabled on the taskbar in Windows. Alt+D will not put focus into *that* address bar.

Comment: It did answer my question tho.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the Windows explorer address bar, simply hit <kbd>F4</kbd>, no need for AtuoHotKey.

Comment: It should be the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

If you mean windows explorer addressbar, then pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> once or twice, depending on where you are, does the trick.

Also, you can find most shortcuts in windows 7 by going to help and support and searching for keyboard shortcuts. This should give you an article with a fairly exhaustive list of shortucts that can be used.